# Functions defined inside functions spawned as processes in Erlang

Tags: erlang

How does a function(A) defined inside another function(B) in which function(B) is a registered process, access the mailbox of function(B)?

Can i define multiple functions in function(B), the function in which the registered process is defined, which can have receive clauses that will access messages sent to function(B) by other processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second paragraph you have answered the first one. The way you get messages (if A and B are in the same process) it's by the `receive` clause. As long as they are in the same process, they will access the same mailbox.

In `function(B)` you can certainly have any number of function calls with  any number of `receive` clauses. Now, if you want them to have the same mailbox, they are to be in the same process and therefore they will be executed in sequence. Also note that the ´receive` clause suspends the execution until something it's received (or the timeout it's reached, if defined).

So in this hypothetical scenario, these *many* functions will  be executed one after another and each one will block the whole process until something it's received (or the timeout it's reached, if defined). Then continue.

Comment: Thank you very much, that really clears things out for me.